# Exception during Collections.sort()

Tags: java, collections, comparator

A `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` is thrown when I do a `Collections.sort()` with a List of `ISimulationResultSet`.
I have not found the reason why contract is not respected.
If someone has a idea of the reason, it will be great to explain.

This is the Comparator I am using :

```
public int compare(ISimulationResultSet r1, ISimulationResultSet r2) {
final float r1Esperance = r1.getResults().getEsperanceGainOuPerte();
    final float r2Esperance = r2.getResults().getEsperanceGainOuPerte();

    final float r1PrctCibleAtteinte = r1.getResults().getPrctCibleAtteinte();
    final float r2PrctCibleAtteinte = r2.getResults().getPrctCibleAtteinte();

    if (r1Esperance / r2Esperance > 1.05F)
         return -1;

    else if (r1Esperance / r2Esperance < 0.95F) {
         return 1;
    }

    else {

        if (r1PrctCibleAtteinte == r2PrctCibleAtteinte) {
            if (r1Esperance > r2Esperance)
               return -1;

             else if (r1Esperance < r2Esperance)
               return 1;

            return 0;
        }

        else if (r1PrctCibleAtteinte > r2PrctCibleAtteinte)
        return -1;

        else if (r1PrctCibleAtteinte < r2PrctCibleAtteinte)
        return 1;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider showing more -- how you're creating your entities to be sorted, how you're calling the sort, the stack trace, etc...

Comment: 1/0.95 = 1.0526... so I guess the comparison is ambigous.

Comment: Move the `return 0;` in the last else statement.

Comment: This nearly always indicates a transitive comparison loop, often because of some default behavior that returns 0 in an attempt to indicate "incomparable" but where a==b and b==c but a!=c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparator has to be symetric, i.e. `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` (`sgn` being the signum function here). This is not the case for your comparator:

Let `a1` and `a2` denote the values of `x.getResults().getEsperanceGainOuPerte()` and `y.getResults().getEsperanceGainOuPerte()` respectively and let `b1` and `b2` denote the values of `x.getResults().getPrctCibleAtteinte()` and `y.getResults().getPrctCibleAtteinte()` respectively.

Now consider the following:

```
1.05 < a1 < 1.052

a2 = 1

b2 > b1
```

Therefore `a2 / a1 > 0.95`

```
compare(x, y) == -1;// first (r1Esperance / r2Esperance > 1.05F) is true

compare(y, x) == -1; // first 3 conditions false, (r1PrctCibleAtteinte > r2PrctCibleAtteinte) is true
```

That violates the contract.

Comment: Fabian, Thank your for your demonstration.
I understand the problem now.

Comment: answer accepted with a very little delay ;-) , sorry :)